# Open a text file with vb.net , and if it exists delete that file

Tags: vb.net, file-io, vb.net-2010

I am writing code for a windows application using vb.net. I want to open a text file under `c:\`. If the file already exists I want to delete that file.

```
my code
-------
 Dim file As String = "C:\test.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(file) Then
        file.Remove(file)
    Else

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file)

  End If
```

I am getting the following error when I try to open that file.

```
error
-----
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: What is your else block doing? trying to run the deleted/ non existing file?

Comment: The code makes no sense since you try to execute the file if it doesn’t exist. Furthermore, note that you **cannot** reliably test for the existence of a file, this is fundamentally impossible since the filesystem doesn’t give you exclusive access to the file (on Unix this is apparently possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from Konrad's point about trying to execute a file that you have just checked does not exist:

1) It's not a good idea to name your variable `file` as it could get confused with System.IO.File.

2) It's File.Delete, not file.Remove - you're calling the String.Remove method because `file` is a string. You should use **Option Strict On** because it would have caught that error for you.

3) On Windows Vista and later, you may not have write/delete access to C:.

Assuming you have write access to the directory C:\temp then this works:

```
Dim fyle As String = "C:\temp\test.txt"

If System.IO.File.Exists(fyle) Then
    IO.File.Delete(fyle)
End If

IO.File.Create(fyle)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fyle)
```

Comment: am not able to open notepad under d:\. the above coding open the notepad with untittled name.

Comment: @sudha.s I can't tell if your comment was added before or after marking my reply as an answer, but when I use `Dim fyle As String = "D:\test.txt"` it works as expected, i.e. it opens my text editor with the file test.txt.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to do this for windows 7, and how to actually get premission ?

Comment: @deltu100 Your question should really be a new thread, but of course you would do a search first and find things like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351429/how-to-elevate-net-application-permissions